# How do you use AJAX using user input?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, forms

I have a project to build a very simple web page which will utilize AJAX to display a result.

In main.py we have a list of words,

```
words = {
    'a': True,
    'aah': True,
    'aahed': True,
    'aahing': True,
    ..............
}
```

And we already have this class defined for us:

```
class CheckWordHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        word = self.request.get('word')
        if word in words:
          self.response.out.write('true')
        else:
          self.response.out.write('false')
    def post(self):
        return self.get()
```

So far this is the only thing I have working on index.html which uses AJAX, whenever you type something it just displayed a new random number. I did this just to get a feel for how it works.

```
function checkWord() {
    var xmlHttp = createXmlHttp();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
            var text = Math.random();
            var d = document.getElementById('texthere');
            d.innerHTML = text;
        }
    }     
    postParameters(xmlHttp, '/check', '');

}
```

But I'm having troubling thinking how to use checkwordhandler to display if the user is typing in a word which is in the list. How would I get the user input to be checked by the handler?

I have a form, where the user can type in anything

```
<form >
    Enter a word:<br>
    <input type="text" onkeypress="checkWord()" name="word">
    <br>
</form>
```

So, how would I go about taking the input from this form and checking if it's in the list of words using xml?

Comment: i would cache the words client side instead of re-requesting them on each keypress.

Comment: What does `postParameters` do?

Comment: postParameters was a function which would have xmlHttp.open(); and xmlHttp.send();

Answer (score 0):

Change the input to send the value that the user has typed:

```
onkeypress="checkWord(this.value)"
```

And change the AJAX function to send the value as a parameter, and show the response text.

```
function checkWord(word) {
    var xmlHttp = createXmlHttp();
    xmlHttp.open('GET', '/check?word=' + encodeURIComponent(word), true);
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
            var text = xmlHttp.responseText;
            var d = document.getElementById('texthere');
            d.innerHTML = text;
        }
    } 
    xmlHttp.send();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! I'm printing out the xmlHttp.responseText() into my webpage to see if it returns "true" or "false", but I keep getting "null". I don't feel like I'm having correct item being returned, but I don't see my error. The correct requests are getting sent though.

Comment: Are you sure `/check` is the correct path for the script? Do you see any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: Yes, check is the correct path. How would CheckWordHandler sned a "true" value using self.response.out.write('true') to xmlHttp.responseXML?? I'm confused as to how they are communicating with one another the two pieces of code.

Comment: You shouldn't use `responseXML` if you're just writing a string, use `responseText`. Do you see the response in the Network tab of the console?

Comment: Yes! That turned out to be my problem! I figured it out the hard way unfortunately...